# How to Find Closest data points for a query data point in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, tabular

I have a query data point with 15 columns and I have a pandas data frame with same columns(15) and i want to find closest data points present in data frame to my query data point. can some one guide me on this ?

Example:
query data point

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

df

```
1  3  5  6
2  7  9  1
2  8  1  8
5  4  9  0
2  4  6  7
```

here, below rows are  closest , in the same way i want to retrieve first n closest data points to my query point.

```
1  3  5  6
2  4  6  7
```

I tried clustering but it was too complex for me to understand and KNN is expecting a target variable, so need your help .Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Euclidean distance or L2Norm to calculate the distance between each row of your dataframe and your query point.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,  3,  5,  6],
[2,  7,  9,  1],
[2,  8,  1,  8],
[5,  4,  9,  0],
[2,  4,  6,  7]])

vec = [1, 2, 3, 4]

dist = df.sub(vec, axis=1).pow(2).sum(axis=1).pow(.5)
```

This gives the output,

```
0    3.000000
1    8.426150
2    7.549834
3    8.485281
4    4.795832
dtype: float64
```

You can select the shortest n distances, which give you the positions of n-closest data points to your query points.

Or you can use the `np.linlag.norm`

```
dist = np.linalg.norm(source.to_numpy() - vec, axis=1)
```

which gives you the output

```
array([3.        , 8.42614977, 7.54983444, 8.48528137, 4.79583152])
```

Check out the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64374482/how-to-calculate-distance-for-every-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-single-poin).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
query_point = [1, 2, 3, 4]
n = 2

n_closest_points = df.loc[(df - query_point).pow(2).sum(axis=1).nsmallest(n).index]
```

gives

```py
   0  1  2  3
0  1  3  5  6
4  2  4  6  7
```

We take the sum of squared distance between each row and the `query_point` by chaining subtraction (which broadcasts), taking square (`pow`) and summing (`sum`). Then we require the `n` closest rows via getting the rows that have the smallest distance (`nsmallest`). Then this gives a series with values being the squared distance and index indicating the desired rows, so we take its index and look them into the original df (`.loc`).